# Issue by implementing a python like "map" function in C++ : call a class member function

Tags: c++, vector, mapreduce, stdvector

I have a function member :

```
double XC::nz(double z){
    return pow(z/zrange_0,2)*exp(-pow(z/zrange_0,1.5));
}
```

I would like to get the equivalent but with vector form, so I did :

```
vector<double> XC::nz_vec(vector<double> input){

    vector<double> output;
    output.resize(input.size());
    transform(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin(), nz);
    return output;
}
```

But compilation is not passed since the call to `nz` function, especially into  `transform(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin(), nz)`.

So, I saw an alternative that could be :

```
    transform(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin(), this->*nz);
```

but compiler still complains.

In my header, I have put :

```
class XC{

...

public:    
       double nz(double);
       vector<double> nz_vec(vector<double>);

}
```

How to circumvent this issue since I want to do in another method of the same class :

```
int numPoints = 100000;
vector<double> nz_vec_min = nz_vec(linspace(zmin[0], zmin[1], numPoints));
vector<double> nz_vec_max = nz_vec(linspace(zmax[0], zmax[1], numPoints));
```

with linspace that returns a vector (like in Python)?

I can set the compiler flag `-std=c++11` or earlier.

Comment: What is the exact compiler error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `nz` is a member function and therefore needs to be called on its associated object.  The easiest way to do this is with a capturing lambda:

```
std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin(), [this] (double d) { return nz (d); });
```

Also, I suggest you pass `input` by `const` reference, rather than by value, since the latter makes a copy.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/InfFg5dQ4OHDGwrj)